# Change tab in tab bar controller using finger swipe

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have three tabs in my tabbar controller and I want to switch between these tabs just like tinder switches the tab using finger touch. I have done it using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` but its not exactly same as that of Tinder (the dating app ) swiping.
I have added `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on one of the `Tabbar controller` and then added the function to change the tabbar selected index. But the animations is not controlled by finger touch. I want the swiping should be controlled by finger touch.

Comment: Have you tried `UIPanGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: Can you suggest me `TabBarControllerAnimation` methods to change the `SelectedIndex` using finger touch and swipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bit late but I found my ans -

I have created 4 UIviewcontrollers programatically and then
created an array of it.

```
var views = [CareTeamTableViewController(),VFCChatQViewController(), NewAccountViewController(), ShareViewController()]
```

Then I added a scrollview in my main UiViewController

```
 private func initMainScroll() {
        scrollView = UIScrollView.init()
        scrollView?.delegate = self
        scrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView?.isPagingEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView!)
    }
```

and then added the views array like :

```
func setupScrollView(complete:()->()) {
        scrollView?.frame = views.first!.view.frame
        scrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(views.count) * UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0)
        _ = views.map({ addViewToScrollView($0) })
        _ = views.map({ $0.view.frame.origin =  CGPoint(x: CGFloat(views.index(of: $0)!) * UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0) })
        complete()
    }

    func addViewToScrollView(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        scrollView?.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        addChildViewController(viewController)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do it is to put all your tab views in a `UIScrollView`. You place them next to each other.

Implement the scroll view delegate methods in your `tabbarController`. 
You'll probably need `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to know on which view you are when the user stops scrolling, like this:

```
let page_width=UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let page=Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-page_width/2)/page_width)+1)
```

Here, I assume each of your tab view is the same size as the screen.

Comment: You don't need `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with the scroll view.

Comment: I have three different `UIViewControllers` in each of the tabs. Therefore adding them to the `UIScrollView` will be difficult.

Comment: You can put 3 containers that hold your view controllers.

Comment: Is there any other method rather than adding a `UIScrollView ` in  `Tabbar controller`?

Comment: If you want a smooth and responsive scroll betweens your views, I don't think so.